# Proof that x in domain of a function F is an element of $ (F^{-1} \circ F) (x)$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Let A and B be two non-empty and finite sets. Let $a\in A$ and $b \in B$.

Let $F:$ $A$ $\rightarrow$ $B$ and $G: B$ $\rightarrow$ $P(A)$ defined by $G(b):= F^{-1}(b) $.

Prove that for all $a$, $a\in (G\circ F)(a)$.

My proof:

By the definition of a function, for every $a\in A$, there is an unique $b=F(a)\in ImF \subseteq B$.

For every $b \in ImF$, $G(b)$ returns a non-empty set containing all $a_i$ such that $F(a_i) = b$.

Therefore, for $a\in A$, $a \in G(b) = G(F(a)) = (G\circ F)(a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is correct but, in my opinion, can be written better. Notice that the above claim does not really require $A$ and $B$ to be nonempty.

Let $A$ and $B$ be nonempty sets and $f\colon A\to B.$ We claim that, for all $a\in A, $ we have
$$a \in (g\circ f)(a)$$
where $g\colon B\to P(A)$ is defined by $g(b) = f^{-1}(b)$ for all $b\in B.$

Let $a\in A$ be arbitrary. Then, as $f\colon A\to B, f(a) \in B.$ Now, by definition of $g\circ f, $ we have
$$(g\circ f)(a) = \{ a'\in A \mid f(a') = f(a) \}.$$
As $a\in A$ and $f(a) = f(a), $ it follows that $a \in (g\circ f)(a).$

---

Please see if this proof feels better written to you.